# submatrix separation from matrices inside cell

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have a question in MATLAB.

I have a 41×1 cell array. Each of the 41 cells consists of a 4×4 matrix and what I need is to get a 41×1 cell array consisting of 2×2 matrices. These 2×2 matrices are the ones in right down corner of the 4×4 matrices.

Comment: Ok, cell-array is matlab, so I hope you ask this for a matlab program/problem?

Comment: @A.H yes this is a matlab question

Comment: Did you try using a for loop? Iterate all elements and select the elements you want.

Comment: @Daniel I dont  know that . can you please explain with an example

Answer (score 2):

No need for a loop.

```
B = cellfun(@(x) x(3:4,3:4),A,'UniformOutput',false)
```

`cellfun` applies the function given as the first argument to each element of the cell array `A`. In this case, the function returns the elements in the lower right hand corner of your 4×4 matrices.

Comment: Extremely thankful to you....Really helpful answer. It really works in my code. Thanks again

Comment: @ReyaRose You're welcome. If the answer was helpful, please consider [upvoting and accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).